# C++ operator overloading

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

Why does the below C++ program output "ACCA"? Why is `operator int()` called twice?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    Base(int m_var=1):i(m_var){
        cout<<"A";
    }
    Base(Base& Base){
        cout<<"B";
        i=Base.i;
    }
    operator int() {
        cout<<"C";
        return i;
    }
private:
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    Base obj;
    obj = obj+obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI; This is a construct made to create ACCA, as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First, this line:

```
Base obj;
```

Default-constructs object `obj` by picking the constructor that accepts an integer, with default value `1`. This is responsible for the first `A` being printed to the standard output.

Then, this expression:

```
obj + obj
```

Requires picking a viable overload of `operator +`. In this case, since `obj` has a user-defined conversion to `int`, the built-in `operator +` is picked, and both arguments are converted to `int`. This is responsible for the two `C`s being printed to the standard output.

Then, the assignment to `obj` in:

```
obj = obj + obj
```

Needs to invoke the implicitly generated `operator =` for `Base`. The implicitly generated `operator =` has signature:

```
Base& operator = (Base const&);
```

This means that the expression on the right side of the equal sign, which is of type `int`, must be converted into a temporary `Base` object from which `obj` is assigned (the reference parameter of the implicitly-generated `operator =` is bound to this temporary).

But the creation of this temporary from an `int` in turn requires invoking the converting construction of `Base` that accepts an `int` again, which is responsible for the second `A` being printed to the standard output.

Answer (score 9):

`operator int()` is called twice because you haven't overloaded `operator+`. The compiler doesn't know how to add a `Base` to a `Base`, so they are converted to `int` (since you taught it how to do that), which it does know how to do. The following code prints `ADA`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    Base(int m_var=1):i(m_var){
        cout<<"A";
    }
    Base(Base& Base){
        cout<<"B";
        i=Base.i;
    }
    operator int() {
        cout<<"C";
        return i;
    }
    int operator+(Base& Base)
    {
        cout<<"D";
        return i+Base.i;
    }
private:
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    Base obj;
    obj = obj+obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When you construct the object, you get the first "A":

```
 Base obj;
```

When you specify to add `obj+obj`, the compiler needs to figure out a way to use `+` on `obj`.  Since you didn't override an `operator+` for `Base`, the conversion to `int()` gets called for each side of the equation:

```
obj+obj
```

This prints `"CC"`.

Then, you assign to `obj`, which is of type `Base`, so the constructor which can accept an int (`i + i` from the `int()` operator) is run, which prints "A":

```
obj = obj+obj; // Assignment prints "A"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
obj = obj+obj;
      ^^^--------obj converted to int here
          ^^^----obj converted to int here
^^^^^------------Base(int) ctor and default operator= called here
```

Overloading cast operators is not generally a good idea unless you understand the costs and know for a fact that the benefits in your specific case outweigh them.

Answer (score 2):

> how does below C++ program computes to "ACCA" ?

The first letter shown is 'A'. This output is related to this line:

```
Base obj;
```

... in which you are creating a new instance of Base.

The next line is a bit complicated:

```
obj = obj+obj;
```

Normally, this is translated to `obj.operator+( obj )`, but you don't have operator + overloaded in class `Base`, so this translation is not valid. The remaining possibility is that operator + is actually the numeric add operator.

And yes, this is possible, since you have provided a cast to `int`. So it is possible to convert each term of the equation in an `int`... and therefore `operator int` is called twice. The actual number of times `operator int` is called depends on the optimizations activated. For example, the compiler could realise that both terms are the same, and then create a new temporary once the `operator int` has been called the first time. In that case, you would see CA instead of CC.

Finally, the assignment expression `obj.operator=( temp )` is executed. And here the keyword is **temp**. In order for the [default](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) `operator=` to work, since it is not overloaded, you have to have a `Base` object at the right. It is actually possible to have it, since `Base` uses an `int` to build new instances. Okay, so the result of `obj + obj` was an `int` (say it is called 'x') number, and the compiler creates a temporary object of class `Base` which is constructed with number *x*, as the following line was executed:

```
Base temp( x );
```

That's the way the final letter seen is an 'A'. Again, many compilers can avoid the building of temporaries on some cases, so it is possible not to see an 'A' at the end.

Note that this line:

```
obj = obj + obj
```

Was thus decomposed in:

```
int x = ( (int) obj ) + ( (int) obj );
Base temp( x );
obj = temp;
```

The final instruction has the result of as if the memory in which `obj` sits will be occupied with the contents of `temp` (that's the role of the default copy constructor, which executes `operator=` for each member of the class, see again the 'rule of three').

Operator overloading involves a lot of issues that maybe are not foreseen if you don't have a more or less deep knowledge of the language, as you can see. Take also into account that languages like Java totally prevent its use, while C# permits it from a controlled perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You refer to obj twice in the expression `obj+obj` and each such reference has to be converted to an integer.

It's not impossible (although it is a horrible idea) that such a conversion could be "stateful" - that is, it could by design return a different value each time it is called. After all, the value represented by `obj` may change (it could be a counter or something like that). So the compiler has to evaluate it afresh for each reference.

Comment: Since the `operator int()` isn't marked `const`, the signature tells the compiler quite directly that it should expect the call to modify the object's state. However even for a const operator, the second call would not be allowed to be optimized away exactly because there might be something like `cout` in it (and here, indeed it is).

Comment: And we can think of a function that has a side-effect (like writing to standard output) as returning a new version of the universe each time it is called, which is another way of interpreting "returning a different value each time it is called".

Answer (score 1):

It's call once per operand, it doesn't matter if it is the same instance.

```
 obj = obj+obj;
```

It "casts" the first operand to an int, and then the second one.

You need to overload the operator + if you want to avoid this implicit cast.

Answer (score 1):

It calls `operator int()` twice because it needs to convert both obj to int before it can add them.

Answer (score 1):

The first A comes from

`Base obj;`

The two Cs come from converting obj in `obj+obj` to `int` as you didn't overload the `operator +`.

The last A comes from `obj =` conversion of the resulting `int` to `obj`.